# How can I save replies in Gmail with the same label

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

In Gmail:
Say when I have an email that has label xyz attached to it, how can I attach the same label/s to any reply?

Comment: If you have _Conversation view_ activated, they will be labeled automatically.

Comment: Where do I find this view

Comment: Gear (upper-right corner) → _Settings_ → _Conversation View_ → set to **on** → **Save Changes**. This, however, will affect the way _all_ your emails are displayed—they will be grouped together. See [here](http://gmailblog.blogspot.it/2010/09/turn-off-gmails-conversation-view.html) for more details.

Comment: Conversation view is the default for Gmail, so unless you've explicitly turned it off it's already on.

Comment: I don't think this is so.  I just turned conversation view off, and seaarched for all messages with a certain subject.  My replies are not tagged.